# fail to call a method

Tags: python, methods

```
class Human(Player):
    def __init__(self,Symbol,gameBoard):
        self.playerSymbol=Symbol
        self.gameBoard=gameBoard
    def nextMove(self):
        print 'nextMove'
```

here is a class but when I call the nextmove method, it's not working, here's the code calling it

```
 player_O.nextMove
 print player_O.playerSymbol
```

and the result is still unchanged:

```
O
```

Comment: Its unclear what error you're seeing, or what you expect to happen. `nextMove` does nothing except print something.

Answer (score 2):

`player_O.nextMove` This is not a function call, it's a function.

To call it, use `player_O.nextMove()`.